# How to Partition rest rows by the first row?

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

Given a list

```
lst = {{{"1","2","3"},{"4","5"},{"6","7","8","9"}},
        { "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"},
        { "9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"}};
```

How to get this by `Partition`.

```
res =  {{{"1","2","3"},{"4","5"},{"6","7","8","9"}},
        {{"A","B","C"},{"D","E"},{"F","G","H","I"}},
        {{"9","8","7"},{"6","5"},{"4","3","2","1"}}};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
lst2 = lst;
lst2[[2 ;;]] = TakeList[Flatten @ #, Length /@ lst[[1]]] & /@ lst[[2 ;;]];
lst2
```

> {{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5"}, {"6", "7", "8", "9"}},
> {{"A", "B",
> "C"}, {"D", "E"}, {"F", "G", "H", "I"}},
> {{"9", "8", "7"}, {"6",
> "5"}, {"4", "3", "2", "1"}}}

You can also use the following to get the same result:

```
lst3 = lst;
lst3[[2 ;;]] //= Map[TakeList[Flatten@#, Length /@ lst[[1]]] &];
lst3

lst4 = lst; 
lst4[[2 ;;]] = Function[x, 
  Module[{k = 0}, Map[x[[k++]] &, lst[[1]], {-1}]]] /@ Rest[lst3];
lst4

MapAt[TakeList[Flatten @ #, Length /@ lst[[1]]] &, lst, {2;;}]

Extract[Flatten @ #, 
  List /@ Module[{k = 1}, Map[k++ &, lst[[1]], {-1}]]] & /@ lst
```

Comment: Thanks! Master who is energetic and always online.;)

Answer (score 4):

```
p = Length /@ First[lst];

res = Prepend[
  Internal`PartitionRagged[#, p] & /@ Rest[lst],
  First[lst]]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}},
>  {{A, B, C}, {D, E}, {F, G, H, I}},
>  {{9, 8, 7}, {6, 5}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The following also works. I removed the brackets

```
Prepend[Table[FoldPairList[TakeDrop, lst[[i]], Length /@ lst[[1]]], {i, 2, Length[lst]}], lst[[1]]]
```

Also, many thanks to kglr for correcting my code.

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, #, Length /@ lst[[1]]] & /@ Rest[lst]
```

Comment: Titus, re "Unfortunately, ..." , just move `&` outside `FoldPairList[...]`, that is, use `FoldPairList[TakeDrop, #, Length /@ lst[[1]]] & /@ Rest[lst]`.

Comment: @kglr thank you very much! I do not handle pure functions well.

Answer (score 4):

We can also use the (undocumented) built-in function `` Internal`CopyListStructure ``:

```
FoldList[Internal`CopyListStructure] @ lst
```

> ```
> {{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5"}, {"6", "7", "8", "9"}},
>  {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"D", "E"}, {"F", "G", "H", "I"}}, 
>  {{"9", "8", "7"}, {"6", "5"}, {"4", "3", "2", "1"}}}
> ```

We can also use a combination of `FoldList` and `TakeList` to get the same result:

```
FoldList[TakeList[Flatten @ #2, Length /@ #] &] @ lst
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lst =
    {{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5"}, {"6", "7", "8", "9"}},
    {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"},
    {"9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"}};
```

Using `Take` and `Table`:

```
l = Flatten /@ lst;

f = MinMax /@ ToExpression /@ First@# &;

Table[Take[l[[i]], #] & /@ (f@#), {i, Length@#}] &@lst

(*{{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5"}, {"6", "7", "8", "9"}},
   {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"D", "E"}, {"F", "G", "H", "I"}},
   {{"9", "8", "7"}, {"6", "5"}, {"4", "3", "2", "1"}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a =
  {{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5"}, {"6", "7", "8", "9"}},
   {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"},
   {"9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"}};

cp = Internal`CopyListStructure;
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[b_ :> cp[First @ a, b], {2 ;;}] @ a;

MatrixForm[%]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
BlockMap[TakeList[#, Length /@ lst[[1]]] &, Flatten@lst, Length@lst[[2]]]


(* 
  {
   {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5"}, {"6", "7", "8", "9"}}, 
   {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"D", "E"}, {"F", "G", "H", "I"}}, 
   {{"9", "8", "7"}, {"6", "5"}, {"4", "3", "2", "1"}}
  } 
 *)
```